# update-function-configuration with more than five security groups

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I am trying to update my lamda function using the AWS CLI command

```
aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name <function_name> --vpc-config SubnetIds=<comma separated subnet ids>,SecurityGroupIds=<comma separated security groups>
```

I have ten security groups and the cli is not allowing me to use more than five.
Am I doing something wrong? How to proceed in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambda uses a network interface to provide VPC connectivity. The soft limit is 5 security groups per network interface. The absolute maximum is 16. You will need to contact AWS to request an increase.

Note: I do not recommend using more than 5 security groups as this will affect your network performance.

Reference link for security group limits:

[Amazon VPC Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/amazon-vpc-limits.html)

How to request an AWS Service Limit increase:

[AWS Service Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible, Lambda has a limit of five security groups. I contacted the AWS support, because I increased the limit of security groups per network interface and still wasn't able to add more than five.

> ... I would like to inform you that unfortunately, even though the "Security groups per network interface" limit has been increased, Lambda service will not allow the user to add more than 5 security groups. This is a hard limit for Lambda and cannot be increased. ...

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_VpcConfig.html#API_VpcConfig_Contents